# Polygon Inequality

Tags: geometry, inequality, polygons

We know that to form a triangle the 3 sides should obey the triangle inequality . So is there any rule to be followed by the sides of $n$-sided convex polygon.
**For Eg:-**
$1,2,4$ cannot form a triangle so can we tell if we are given $n$ line segments can we make a $n$-sided convex polygon.

Comment: ^But is this condition a sufficient one to make a convex polygon if you are given n sides??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The longest side must be shorter than the sum of the rest.

Comment: (+1)Ok, Do you have any proof or any source ?

Comment: The shortest distance between two points is a straight line, and the other sides form a path from one endpoint of the longest side to the other, which must have greater length than the length of that side.                                   Must a convex n-gon exist for all sets of side lengths satisfying the above rule?

Comment: @Mod Let $A_1..A_n$ be the polygon. Then $A_1A_3 < A_1A_2+A_2A_3$. Now use induction, look at $A_1A_3A_4..A_n$.

Comment: put all the non-longest in a line segment $L$, which exceeds the length of the longest side, at a certain angle from it. Now using the juncture points in $L$ you can "bend" $L$ outward from the long side until the tip of $L$ is at distance equal to the length of the long side from one end, then rotate to close into a convex figure.