# Constructable Figures with given lengths

Tags: geometry

This may be an already solved question. Let us be given with *l* lengths ***AB*** , ***BC*** , … , ***LM*** , *l* being  *l* ≥ 3. What is the condition that we can construct a figure with them? And what is the least dimension ***n*** required to do so? Is there a general solution for this question?

My question is not restricted to polygons but also includes polyeders, cells, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If by "*figure*" you mean a polygon where $\,M \equiv A\,$ then the necessary and sufficient condition is $\,AB+BC+\ldots+LM \ge 2 \cdot \max(AB, BC, \ldots , LM)\,$, which follows from the triangle inequality. This holds in any dimension $\,n \ge 2\,$, and such a polygon can in fact be constructed in a $2$-dimensional subspace of the $n$-dimensional space once the condition is satisfied.

Comment: @김세현 That's equivalent to saying that the *longest* side must be no longer than the sum of the rest. That's a necessary condition as follows directly from the triangle inequality, see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/413764/polygon-inequality) or [here](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-necessary-conditions-for-n-sides-to-form-a-polygon-when-the-length-of-sides-are-given).